# Is there a keyboard shortcut to remove a table in libreoffice writer ?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I tried selecting the whole table and Ctrl-backspace or Ctrl-del, none worked.
Libreoffice 4.2.8.2, Linux Mint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Ctrl-Shift-del`, also, this answere needs 30 characters to get validated and I'm going to get downvoted and/or edited for this comment.

Comment: Love this answer - thank you for making it! Hope you'll keep it so I can have a a canonical reference showing the absurdity of SE-rules 

Comment: @rusi check this out. I'm going to get banned for this : https://twitter.com/slipperyseal/status/598324845647040513

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut for deleting an entire table, and AFAIK there's no way to set a single shortcut - at least there's no function "Delete Table" in Menu Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard, Category Table.

[image]

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> <strike>doesn't work for me, since this is by default the shortcut for "Delete to end of sentence"</strike> works, but you'll have to select the whole table first (you may assign a shortcut to the "Select Table" Function using Menu `Tools` -> `Customize` -> `Keyboard`, Category `Table`, Entry "Select Table").

Alternatively, you may call the "Delete Table" menu entry very easily using the keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (menu Table) -> <kbd>D</kbd> (Delete) -> <kbd>T</kbd> (Table):

[image]

Comment: You have to select the whole table before then go `ctrl-shift-del`, it worked for my configuration (maybe you have a different config ?)

Comment: Couldn't edit my previous comment, here's a [screencast](https://vimeo.com/154153632) showing how it works

Comment: Ah - ok, you're right: `ctrl-shift-del` works after selecting the whole table first. But IMHO navigating to the `Delete Table` entry in the `Table` menu using the keyboard is faster (you don't need to select anything first). So, to sum up: there's no straightforward solution, but two nice workarounds :-)